# Find specific strings in a large text asynchronous way python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Im trying to design and implement a simple python program to find specific strings in a large text.
I designed the code to work asynchronous, trying to use `asyncio` and `aiohttp` packages, but nothing seems close to work, so im trying to start over completely.
I want my code will answer following concepts:

1. A main module - reads a large text file in parts (e.g. 1000 lines in each part) and
   sends each part (as string) to a matcher. After all matchers completed, it calls the
   aggregator to combine and print the results
2. A matcher - gets a text string as input and searches for matches of a given set of
   strings. The result is a map from a word to its location(s) in the text
3. A aggregator - aggregates the results from all the matchers and prints the results.

Example of one line from the program output based on the input above:

```
Timothy --> [[lineOffset=13000, charOffset=19775], [lineOffset=13000, charOffset=42023]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd look into map-reduce. Flagging for closing because you didn't post any code, errors, or anything really useful for answering your question. https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Comment: @mikeb this because nothing that i've done was even close to solve a part of the issue. Will it help if i post a code that is completely wrong conceptually?